# curl limit the progress output by size

Tags: curl

In `wget` we can limit the progress output by size like this.

However, I didn't find an equivalent of this in `curl`.

curl has `-#` option that prints the dot, but how can we limit the dot by size?

eg

```
wget --progress=dot -e dotbytes=10M
```

Comment: No, curl has no such option.

Answer (score 0):

No, curl has no such option. Room for future improvements I guess!

Comment: Is this still not available in curl to this day?